# YUI drag&drop proxy drag

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, yui

Question for YUI experts...

I have a table and I've made each cell of the first row draggable by [proxy](http://web.archive.org/web/20160728103125/https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/dragdrop/dd-proxy.html). In IE, when the drag proxy is released, the original table cell actually jumps to wherever the release point was. How can I prevent this from happening? Essentially, I want to know where the proxy was dropped and handle my logic from there but I don't want the original to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the drop-functions, check for

`DD::dragOverEvent( )`

`DD:endDragEvent( )`

functions on this reference:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.DD.html